# making 2 JsonObjectRequests using volley

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley

I am using Volley library to handle internet requests.
The problem is I need to make two requests. The first one needed to retrieve an id and then using that id to make the second request and retrieve final data. I don't know how to do it, I used AsyncTask but it didn't work for me.

When I add the second request after the `onResponse` of the first request, I got this error :

```
E/Volley: [2365] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException
                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
                                               at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:521)
                                               at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:92)
                                               at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
                                               at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)
```

Comment: so what kind of problem do you have? just make the second request after you got the response from the first

Comment: the problem is the id always passed null, I mean the second request is executed before retrieving the id (finishing the  first request)

Comment: so make the second request after receiving the response from the first request

Comment: When I add it after the onResponse, I've got this D/Volley: [1] 6.onErrorResponse: Product Error in the first request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you need to create and add the second request only after `onResponse` is called for the first one, should be too much of an issue

Comment: When I add it after the `onResponse`, I've got this `D/Volley: [1] 6.onErrorResponse: Product Error` in the first request